# Does it make sense to deploy TURN and media server in the same network?

Tags: webrtc, turn, coturn

Suppose, we have a media server `S` deployed. We have a client `C` who is behind a symmetric NAT. The direct WebRTC media streaming is not possible due to symmetric NAT. So we want to deploy a TURN server `T`, which would relay all media between `S` and `C`.

Now, it seems that developers sometime deploy `T` near `S` for simplicity. But does it help to stream media between `C` and `S`? "Near" means "in the same network", so `S` and `T` are behind the same NAT if there is some. Since, they are behind the same NAT, it doesn't seem to improve connectivity: chances to stream WebRTC traffic between `S` and `C` are the same as between `T` and `C`.

Is this reasoning correct or am I missing something? In my current understanding, TURN servers act like a proxy with better connectivity with respect to `C`. So they should be placed in another network to make any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C` -> `T` can do a few things that `C` -> `S` can't do

- DTLS and TLS transport, ICE only allows UDP and TCP. Some gateways only allow TLS on 443
- Single port, you can do all traffic on one well know port. Gateway may only allow `:443`
- `S` may not support `ICE-TCP`. Some SFUs do support it though!

Comment: Thanks, exactly sort of information I was looking for. What would you say in case of Janus? It supports fallback to TCP and I can set arbitrary port with it, so only point about DTLS/TLS remains?

Comment: Are you able to have multiple connections on one port? With TURN you can run multiple associations over one port, I am not familiar with libnice (what Janus uses) if that happens! If you set a port range of 1 can you connect multiple browsers?